# Como puedo consultar el usuario con mas ventas en 2 tablas distintas

Tags: mysql

Tengo 3 tablas (user, ventat, pint).
Mayor cantidad ventas_t

```
SELECT user.nombre, COUNT(*) AS ventas_t FROM ventat
INNER JOIN user
ON ventat.id_num_usu = user.id_user
GROUP BY user.nombre
ORDER BY ventas_t DESC
```

mayor cantidad ventas_pint

```
SELECT user.nombre, COUNT(*) AS ventas_pint FROM pint
INNER JOIN user
ON pint.id_num_usu = user.id_user
GROUP BY user.nombre
ORDER BY ventas_pint DESC
```

seleccionar el usuario que mayor ventas tiene contando las veces que aparece en las 2 tablas

```
SELECT DISTINCT
user.nombre,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pint WHERE pint.id_num_usu = user.id_user) AS ventas_pint,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventat WHERE ventat.id_num_usu = user.id_user) AS ventas_t
FROM user
ORDER BY ventas_pint DESC, ventas_t DESC
```

No trare el resultado que espero.
También lo replanteo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT user.nombre, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pint WHERE pint.id_num_usu = user.id_user) AS ventas_pintyt, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventat WHERE ventat.id_num_age = user.id_user) AS ventas_tyt,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pint WHERE pint.id_num_usu = user.id_user) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventat WHERE ventat.id_num_age = user.id_user)) AS total
FROM user
WHERE user.id_user = 1122
```

Me funciona trae resultados.
Pero al quitarle el where para ver no solo 1 registro en específico sale un error:

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'user.nombre'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Saludos...

Comment: Consulta el siguiente [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53868c/4) estuve revisando y no encontré ningún problema en tu planteamiento, tal vez puedas comparar para ver donde esta tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con tu última query es que estás usando la función de agregación `SUM()` y no estás agrupando (Para sumar dos columnas de la misma fila utiliza solo el `+`).

Para obtener el usuario con mas ventas (en ambas tablas) tienes que sumar ambos `count(*)` y ordenar de acuerdo a dicha suma `DESC`. Con `LIMIT 1` la query te retornará solo el usuario con mas ventas (la suma de las ventas en ambas tablas):

```
SELECT user.nombre,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pint WHERE pint.id_num_usu = user.id_user) AS ventas_pint,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventat WHERE ventat.id_num_usu = user.id_user) AS ventas_t
FROM user
ORDER BY (ventas_pint + ventas_t) DESC;
```

Yo plantearía la query de esta forma (si bien el resultado es el mismo, es mas eficiente). Primero obtengo el total de ventas por usuario (`subuqery v`) y el total de pint por usuario (`subquery p`), luego vinculo la tabla `user` con ambas subqueries (utilizando `LEFT JOIN`) y sumo los count(*):

```
SELECT u.nombre, 
       coalesce(v.cantidad_ventat, 0) AS cantidad_ventat,
       coalesce(p.cantidad_pint, 0) AS cantidad_pint, 
       coalesce(v.cantidad_ventat, 0) + coalesce(p.cantidad_pint, 0) AS total
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_num_usu, count(*) AS cantidad_ventat FROM ventat GROUP BY id_num_usu) AS v ON v.id_num_usu = u.id_user
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_num_usu, count(*) AS cantidad_pint FROM pint GROUP BY id_num_usu) AS p ON p.id_num_usu = u.id_user
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Si quitas el `LIMIT 1` te retornará todos los usuarios ordenados de acuerdo a la suma de ventas de ambas tablas descendente.